# ngx bootstrap datepicker remove arrows

Tags: angular, datepicker, ngx-bootstrap

I am pretty new on working with Angular and Bootstrap and i have a problem. I use a ngx bootstrap datepicker, but i want to remove the standard arrows on the buttons of the datepicker calendar. Here is my printscreen of the problem

[image]

Can somebody help me

Greetz,

Youri

Comment: search about ViewEncapsulation.none, or use !important in your class

Comment: thank you for your answer. This is the code: <button _ngcontent-c20="" class="btn btn-default btn-secondary btn-sm pull-right float-right" tabindex="-1" type="button">›</button>. The problem is that it is the arrow between "button"> > </button>. So i cant not change with in the css, i think with a class !important

Answer (score 0):

Try (I don't use ngx-bootstrap and I'm not sure)

```
.bs-datepicker-head .next {
    display: none;
}
```